# Strange cast in Log4J 1.2 docs

Tags: java, log4j

I was looking through Log4J docs and stumbled at the following in the description of [`Logger#setLevel()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level)) (inherited from `Category`) method:

> If you are passing any of `Level.DEBUG`, `Level.INFO`, `Level.WARN`,
>   `Level.ERROR`, `Level.FATAL` as a parameter, you need to case them as
>   `Level`. As in
>
> ```
> logger.setLevel((Level) Level.DEBUG);
> ```

Is there any reason behind such requirement?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: That's quite nonsense. Might have been a historical artifact. You definitely don't need that cast.

Comment: But you also shouldn't be using 1.2 anymore.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - not my choice. That what the primary vendor has used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a documentation error that was introduced when [`Category.setPriority()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#setPriority%28org.apache.log4j.Priority%29) was deprecated and [`Category.setLevel()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#setLevel%28org.apache.log4j.Level%29) was added in the 1.2 version.

This is how the `setPriority` method originally looked like in [`jakarta-log4j-1.1.3`](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/log4j/source/jakarta-log4j-1.1.3.zip):

```
/**
 Set the priority of this Category.
 <p>Null values are admitted.
*/
public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}
```

Looking at the source for `setPriority` in [`log4j-1.2.17`](https://archive.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17-sources.jar), we can see that when the method was deprecated, a narrowing cast to `Level` was added:

```
/**
 Set the level of this Category.
 <p>Null values are admitted.
 @deprecated Please use {@link #setLevel} instead.
*/
public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
   this.level = (Level) priority;
}
```

So, it seems like an implementation detail of `setPriority` somehow slipped into the JavaDocs of the new `setLevel` method. Obviously, the documentation makes no sense as the cast is not required.

Comment: I had this suspicion but was not able to find any evidence.  Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to give a definitive answer, but this seemed like the most logical explanation to me.